# Serializing empty case classes with Jackson

Tags: json, scala, jackson

Is it possible to include type info when serializing empty case class with Jackson? It returns just an empty object, `{}`. Interestingly, empty Java classes include `@class` property if `SerializationFeatures.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` is disabled. The code in question

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
case class Initial()

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(Initial)
```